# The name 'Fix' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-conversion

In my project I am converting some vb.net to c# and I came to this line:

```
int thisdigit = Fix(countervalue / (Math.Pow(10, (numdigits - j - 1)))) - Fix(countervalue / (Math.Pow(10, (numdigits - j)))) * 10;
```

But I get the error:

```
The name 'Fix' does not exist in the current context
```

How do I fix this?  I can't understand why Fix() wouldn't exist.
But if I used `Math.Truncate()` instead, well, that doesn't work because `thisdigit` is an `int`.
How could I change that?

Here is my original vb.net code:

```
dim dg as int
dg = Fix(value / (10 ^ (digits - j - 1))) - Fix(value / (10 ^ (digits - j))) * 10
```

Here is a link to what I'm trying to convert:
https://www.developerfusion.com/code/3734/aspnet-graphical-page-hit-counter/

The code works in my vb.net projects.  I've run my converted code through the debugger, and the only place I can see any problem is with this line.

I came up with this, too:

```
double thisdigit = Math.Truncate((double)(countervalue / (10 ^ (numdigits - j - 1)))) - Math.Truncate(((double)(countervalue / (10 ^ (numdigits - j))) * 10));
```

Comment: What's does fix do in VB.net code? Why did you write this code?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Fix` in VB anyway. That's a VB6 hold-over, which is why it is specific to VB.NET and not C#. If you wrote "proper" VB.NET code to begin with then you could pretty much append a semicolon and the C# conversion would be done. What you should do is get a proper understanding of what your code is actually doing, write the best .NET code you can in VB to do that, then convert that to C#.

Comment: There are a bunch of types and members in the Microsoft .VisualBasic.dll library, under the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, that are basically reimplementations of VB6 types and members. They exist mainly so that VB6 code can be upgraded to VB.NET without lots of changes, and also so that VB6 developers feel more at home with VB.NET. You can use those types and functions in C# if you reference that library but that is generally a bad idea. `Fix` is actually a member of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion` module, which can be treated as a static class in C#.

Comment: I didn't write the original code...

Comment: @JohnG Uh, all the numbers in the string are already `int`. The problem with that line is that if I use `Math.Truncate()` instead of `Fix()` it won't work because `Math.Truncate()` only works on `double`.

Comment: Why not just cast the result of `Math.Truncate` to an int: `(int)Math.Truncate(...)`?

Comment: Eh, because before this exercise, I was stupid.  hee hee.  I'm still learning the intracacies of C#, in fact.  I didn't really know I could do that on the fly that way.  But in my solution below, you can see I've figured it out with the use of casting for `Math.Pow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why this is so convoluted..

The original code seems to draw a counter, one digit at a time:

```
dim j as Integer, dg as Integer
for j = 0 to (digits-1)
   ' Extract digit from value
   dg = fix(value / (10^(digits - j - 1))) - fix(value / (10^(digits - j)))*10
   ' Add digit to the output graphic
   g.drawimage(i, New rectangle(j*dgwidth, 0, dgwidth, dgheight), New rectangle(dg*dgwidth, 0, dgwidth, dgheight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
   
next j
```

But surely it would just be easier to do something like:

```cs
int pageCounter = 7234283;

string toDraw = pageCounter.ToString();

for(int i = 0; i < toDraw.Length; i++)
    someGraphics.DrawString(toDraw.Substring(i, 1), someFont, someBrush, new PointF(i * 10.0f, 0));
```

Or perhaps:

```
int pageCounter = 7234283;

string toDraw = pageCounter.ToString();

PointF p = new PointF(0.0f, 0.0f);

foreach(char c in toDraw){
    someGraphics.DrawString(c.ToString(), someFont, someBrush, p);
    p.X += 10.0f;
}
```

Comment: I posted what I came up with that works very nicely.  However, you suggested something similar, so I'm going to mark yours as the solution since I don't like accepting my own answers...

Comment: I was also going to say that in essence it looks like the VB code takes an int like 723421 and breaks it into digits of 7, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1 from left to right by doing int division of powers of ten.. But if you wanted to do it muerically like this it might make for simpler code to repeatedly mod/divide by 10 and work from right to left, also painting from right to left, by painting at X = 60, then X = 50 ... so the for loop looks like "paint the modulo 10, divideassign by 10.."

Answer (score 1):

With some help from Aidy in the C# Discord, I ended up with this.  Very simple and clean.

```
//Get the number of digits to display in the output graphic
//If the countervalue is 16 then "16".ToString("D5") converts it to "00016".  
//ToCharArray() turns that into an array of characters ['0', '0', '0', '1', '6']. 
//We loop through that list and convert the char back to int and we get 0, 0, 0, 1 and 6.
//Thanks to @Aidy in the C# Discord for help on this

int numdigits = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["digits"]);
var digits = countervalue.ToString("D" + numdigits.ToString()).ToCharArray();

//Create an output object
Bitmap imageoutput = new Bitmap(digitwidth * digits.Length, digitheight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);  //should be 5*15 = 75 for digits.gif
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(imageoutput);  //here is our black box

//digits.gif is 150 x 20px; 
//So, if our countervalue = 16, and numdigits = 5, we want to display 00016.

for(int j = 0; j < digits.Length; j++) {
    //We loop through that digits and convert the char back to int and we get 0, 0, 0, 1 and 6.
    int thisdigitX = int.Parse(digits[j].ToString());

    //add the digit to the output graphic 
    graphic.DrawImage(digitpix, new Rectangle(j * digitwidth, 0, digitwidth, digitheight), new Rectangle(thisdigitX * digitwidth, 0, digitwidth, digitheight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

However, I was also able to get the original code to work with the conversion of int and double and importing the Visual Basic assembly.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
  int thisdigitX = Conversion.Fix(countervalue / ((int)Math.Pow(10, (double)(numdigits - j - 1)))) - ( Conversion.Fix(countervalue / ((int)Math.Pow(10,(double)(numdigits - j)))) * 10);
```

Here is a link to my github page where I've posted the [entire working project](https://github.com/BGMcoder/C-Sharp) if anyone is really interested.  (not self-promoting here - just sharing; I don't care if anyone uses it or not).